# Netflix ice doesn't work after setting custom tags

Tags: ubuntu, netflix, ice

I'm trying to work with Netflix ICE and trying to use breakdown feature to filter data based on custom tags however, the process always stuck at the following line.

[com.netflix.ice.basic.BasicManagers] INFO  basic.BasicManagers  - trying to find new tag group and data managers...

Without setting custom tag in ice.properties everything looks fine.

defined custom tags like this: user:TagName

I'm kind of stuck at this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ankit